# Tooltip fliks in mouseover event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a map who is mapped with coords to show tooltip like this:

```js
var areas = document.getElementsByTagName('area');
var tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');
for (var i = 0; i < areas.length; i++) {
  areas[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", updateTooltip);
  areas[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", removeTooltip)
}

function updateTooltip() {
  tooltip.style.display = "block"
  tooltip.innerHTML = this.getAttribute('data-text');
  var coordinates = this.getAttribute('coords').split(',')
  tooltip.style.left = coordinates[0] + 'px';
  tooltip.style.top = coordinates[coordinates.length - 1] + 'px';
}

function removeTooltip() {
  tooltip.style.display = "none"
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 150px;
  background: white;
}

area {
  position: relative;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img id="mapImage" src="https://i.imgur.com/Y7HuHDQ.png" usemap="#image-map">

  <map name="image-map">

            <area target="" data-text="USA Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173" alt="USA" title="USA" href="" coords="110,140,182,141,186,148,198,146,198,140,214,139,224,134,234,143,221,150,213,154,205,156,205,170,199,174,194,181,193,188,162,182,158,171,149,173,145,179,141,170,124,168,121,173,112,168,105,158" shape="poly">
            
             <area target="" data-text="Mexico Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173"  alt="MEXICO" title="MEXICO" href="" coords="124,172,137,171,141,178,152,173,160,181,162,204,179,199,179,211,157,212,173,216,146,204,136,196,125,188" shape="poly">
             
             <area target="" data-text="Japan Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173"  alt="JAPAN" title="JAPAN" href="" coords="705,106,716,106,721,146,687,184,667,175" shape="poly">
             
             <area target="" data-text="Germany Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173"  alt="GERMANY" title="GERMANY" href="" coords="418,111,436,108,433,124,418,124" shape="poly">
          <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip"></div>   
    </map>

</div>
```

As you can see in mouse hover it show some tooltip, problem is in USA and Mexico tooltip flik alot, someone knows how to solve it? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because once the tooltip pops up the mouse is now over the tooltip, which triggers the `mouseleave` event you've registered. You can prevent this by adding the css attribute `pointer-events:none` on the tooltip to prevent it from firing events.

I've modified your example below!

```js
var areas = document.getElementsByTagName('area');
var tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');
for (var i = 0; i < areas.length; i++) {
  areas[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", updateTooltip);
  areas[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", removeTooltip)
}

function updateTooltip() {
  tooltip.style.display = "block"
  tooltip.innerHTML = this.getAttribute('data-text');
  var coordinates = this.getAttribute('coords').split(',')
  tooltip.style.left = coordinates[0] + 'px';
  tooltip.style.top = coordinates[coordinates.length - 1] + 'px';
}

function removeTooltip() {
  tooltip.style.display = "none"
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 150px;
  background: white;
  
  /* ADDED */
  pointer-events:none;
}

area {
  position: relative;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img id="mapImage" src="https://i.imgur.com/Y7HuHDQ.png" usemap="#image-map">

  <map name="image-map">

            <area target="" data-text="USA Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173" alt="USA" title="USA" href="" coords="110,140,182,141,186,148,198,146,198,140,214,139,224,134,234,143,221,150,213,154,205,156,205,170,199,174,194,181,193,188,162,182,158,171,149,173,145,179,141,170,124,168,121,173,112,168,105,158" shape="poly">
            
             <area target="" data-text="Mexico Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173"  alt="MEXICO" title="MEXICO" href="" coords="124,172,137,171,141,178,152,173,160,181,162,204,179,199,179,211,157,212,173,216,146,204,136,196,125,188" shape="poly">
             
             <area target="" data-text="Japan Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173"  alt="JAPAN" title="JAPAN" href="" coords="705,106,716,106,721,146,687,184,667,175" shape="poly">
             
             <area target="" data-text="Germany Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173"  alt="GERMANY" title="GERMANY" href="" coords="418,111,436,108,433,124,418,124" shape="poly">
          <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip"></div>   
    </map>

</div>
```